# Mouse position to map coordinates in Rviz?

Tags: rviz, turtlebot2, turtlebot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to find a way of clicking on the map in Rviz and obtaining the coordinates of the map itself at that point. Is there a way of going about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284624/mouse-position-to-map-coordinates-in-rviz?/) by [sy126](https://answers.ros.org/users/34030/sy126/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a duplicate of #q69019. See that question for a few options which may be used to get this sort of info. They're all not really meant for it, but it works well enough for some use-cases.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0